# How to configure the bootstrap image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I inserted an image into a  tag by giving it a class of `.img-circle`. Now the circle that it yielded is too small and I want to increase the radius.
I even tried giving the `<img>` tag an attribute of `width="35px"`, but the image circle did not change.

Please, suggest CSS3 methods or with jQuery.

Comment: If this doesn't make sense , spare me , I am a newbie - - just learning ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img-circle` Bootstrap class only formats the border in such way that it takes the circle form:

```
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

It does not affect the size of your image at all.
You only need to increase your image and this "circle" will increase with it.

Here is the example with three images of type `img-circle` with different sizes described by CSS classes or inline styling:

```css
.big-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.small-image {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Original square image -->
<img class="big-image" src="http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2014/07/Google-Material-Design_dezeen_468_3.jpg"/>
<!-- Big circle image with CSS class rule -->
<img class="img-circle big-image" src="http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2014/07/Google-Material-Design_dezeen_468_3.jpg"/>
<!-- Small circle image with CSS class rule -->
<img class="img-circle small-image" src="http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2014/07/Google-Material-Design_dezeen_468_3.jpg"/>
<!-- Circle image with inline style -->
<img class="img-circle" style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" src="http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2014/07/Google-Material-Design_dezeen_468_3.jpg"/>
```